# Average of a fixed number of rows

Tags: awk

Given the following input:

```
 256 1 4 1 130.363
 256 1 4 2 128.332
 256 1 4 3 130.262
 256 1 4 4 128.395
 256 1 4 5 128.484
 64 2 4 1 95.227
 64 2 4 2 96.582
 64 2 4 3 95.785
 64 2 4 4 93.944
 64 2 4 5 97.398
 64 4 4 1 143.519
 64 4 4 2 143.579
 64 4 4 3 143.937
 64 4 4 4 142.292
 64 4 4 5 143.304
```

I am trying to obtain the average of a given number of rows. In this case, I've got **5** **sample**s indicated by the **4th column**. So the expected output should be:

```
256 1 4 129.167
64 2 4  95.787
64 4 4  143.326
```

To loop over, I have tried something like

```
awk 'BEGIN {i = 1; while (s[$4] <= 5) { print $4 } }'
```

But it is not even printing what I want. Also tried this

```
awk  '{array[$1" "$2]+=$5} END { for (i in array) {print i" " array[i]/length(array)}}'
```

Comment: the number don't average right. Can you recheck the stats again?

Comment: @NinjaGaiden Sorry, let me double check this

Comment: `129.167` instead of `105.965`, right?

Comment: Thats correct. (if my answer is right mark it as the answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{curr = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3} curr!=prev {if (cnt) print prev, sum/cnt; prev=curr; sum=cnt=0} {sum+=$5; cnt++} END{if (cnt) print prev, sum/cnt}' file
256 1 4 129.167
64 2 4 95.7872
64 4 4 143.326
```

The differences between this and @NinjaGaiden's solution are that:

1. This relies on all the data associated with key values being
   contiguous as shown in your sample input while NGs does not.
2. This does not save the contents of the input file in memory while NGs does.
3. This will print the output in the same order it occurred in the input while NGs will print it in random (hash) order.

Comment: interesting solution. +1

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton for very nice solution, just wanted to add here this will work when Input_file is in a sort order(which I agree OP has shown us like that only), thought this could be added as a point  if needed.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I did say that - that's item `1.` in my answer. It doesn't have to be sorted, though, just contiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
awk '{k=$1" "$2" "$3; j[k]+=$5;z[k]+=1} END { for (x in j) { print x,j[x]/z[x] }} ' f
```

Comment: FYI you can use `z[k]++` instead of `z[k]+=1`. Also rather than hard-coding blank chars, it's generally better to use `OFS` between the subscript components when you're going to print the subscripts, e.g. write it as `k=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3` - imagine the difference when you decide to output CSV, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk  '{array[$1" "$2" "$3]+=$5} END { for (i in array) {print i" " array[i]/length(array)}}'
```

Comment: you don't want to get length(array) because its too inclusive. You want to account for only $1,$2,$3

Comment: awk -v n=5 '{ a[$1" "$2" "$3]+=$5 } END { for (i in a) { print i, (a[i] / n) }}'  file

Answer (score 0):

This also work with a variable number of rows

```
awk '
{
    a[$1" "$2" "$3]+=$5
    b[$1" "$2" "$3]++
} END { for (i in a) { print i, (a[i] / b[i]) }} 
' file
```